# How to automatically block camera access after closing camera

Tags: security, camera, quick-settings

Ever since Android added the camera and mic access shortcuts and the quick access menu, I've often found myself forgetting to click the 'block camera access' shortcut after I'm done taking a picture or video. How might one set this feature so that it blocks access immediately after closing the camera app, or after a certain period of inactivity?